# CypherError during graph create/merge using Neo4j-Python Connector

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher

Hi I am getting the following error while trying to create/merge nodes and relationships. It does not always happens but it occurs once in a while.

> CypherError: An unexpected failure occurred, see details in the
>   database logs, reference number eaf50bff-deca-4055-9450-6a76c31534e4.

This is the traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CypherError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-9700f3a5d3fa> in <module>()
      7     tx.success = True
      8     #tx.close()
----> 9   session.close()

/databricks/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4j/v1/session.pyc in close(self)
    522         """
    523         if self.last_result:
--> 524             self.last_result.buffer()
    525         if self.transaction:
    526             self.transaction.close()

/databricks/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4j/v1/session.pyc in buffer(self)
    246         if self.connection and not self.connection.closed:
    247             while not self._consumed:
--> 248                 self.connection.fetch()
    249             self.connection = None
    250
```

My code for create/merge is this:

```
for chunk in chunk_list: 
  with session.begin_transaction() as tx:
    for record in chunk:
      tx.run("MERGE (source:UID {userid : {m}, timestamp: {a}})"
             "MERGE (target:UID {userid : {n}, timestamp: {a}})"
             "MERGE (source)-[:HasConnection]-(target)", {"m": record.source, "n": record.target, "a": record.unix_timestamp_s})
    tx.success = True
    #tx.close()
  session.close()
```

chunk_list is a list containing multiple lists of records. Each of the list within chunk_list has multiple rows (approx 10000) and each row contains three columns, source, target and timestamp.

For each list within chunk_list we are opening a session then doing the merge operations and then closing the session.

The problem starts to happen when the graph exceeding more than 10 million nodes. Lets say for Day 1 the chunk_list has 4 million rows, it would work fine, for Day 2 if the chunk_list has 4 million rows it would work fine as well. But if on Day 3 there are 3 million rows and the total number of nodes is more than 10 million overall in the Neo4j graph then the problem starts to happen.

Comment: Since you're merging :UID nodes with both userid and timestamp, am I correct in that the userid + timestamp combination is the unique lookup key to a :UID, meaning there can be multiple :UIDs with the same userid but different timestamps? Or is userid the unique lookup key, and you're trying to update the timestamps and create a connection?

Comment: It should be same userid but timestamp will change during merging operation. @InverseFalcon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened because the database ran out of disk space which was recorded in the log.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons this is taking so long to execute is that your query is not doing what you think it's doing.

Doing a MERGE is like trying to first do a MATCH, and if no matches are found, then doing a CREATE.

In your comment, you said that the timestamp should change during the MERGE operation, so what you really want to do is an update of the properties for nodes with the same userid, but that's not what your MERGE is doing.

Your MERGE is first trying to MATCH a :UID node with the given userid and timestamp, but there won't be such a node in your graph, since the timestamp is new...there will be a :UID node with the same userid, but with a different timestamp, so no match will be found, and a brand new :UID node will be created with the same userid as an existing node, and the new timestamp.

So your MERGE is always going to be creating new nodes, and never matching on existing nodes. MERGE on its own will never update property values, so never try to use it that way.

To perform a match and an update, you need to MERGE based only on the minimal unique properties to match on an existing node, and then use SET to update properties, like this:

```
for chunk in chunk_list: 
  with session.begin_transaction() as tx:
    for record in chunk:
      tx.run("MERGE (source:UID {userid : {m}})"
             "SET source.timestamp = {a}"
             "MERGE (target:UID {userid : {n}})"
             "SET target.timestamp = {a}"
             "MERGE (source)-[:HasConnection]-(target)", {"m": record.source, "n": record.target, "a": record.unix_timestamp_s})
    tx.success = True
    #tx.close()
  session.close()
```

Additionally, to ensure that your MERGEs are fast, you need to have either an index or a unique constraint on :UID(userid), otherwise neo4j will have to do a label scan to find the nodes, which is far too slow for the size of your graph.

EDIT

I haven't used Python with Neo4j yet, but I'm not sure this kind of loop is the correct means of processing multiple records, as it looks like it will run a huge humber of copies of the given Cypher segment. 5 lines of Cypher per row seems extreme...ideally you should be using Cypher code to operate on all rows simultaneously (or at least the rows per chunk), with your input being easily converted into rows for execution.

A better approach might be to use a loop to generate a list of objects (with "m" and "n" properties), and submit the list and a single timestamp as parameters to the query.

You can then UNWIND the list in your Cypher back into rows, and use that. So, if "row" was your list of objects parameter, and "a" remained your unix timestamp parameter, the Cypher segment would look like:

```
UNWIND {row} as line
MERGE (source:UID {userid : line.m})
SET source.timestamp = {a}
MERGE (target:UID {userid : line.n})
SET target.timestamp = {a}
MERGE (source)-[:HasConnection]-(target)
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction and the problem was related to disk space.

Comment: Edited my answer to point out that the given means of using a loop for generating the Cypher transaction might not be the correct means of approaching this.